# Android Context object's reference in User defined Class

Tags: android, android-activity, reference, android-context

I have a very simple code which displays a `Toast` message upon a `Button` click

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button clickMe;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    clickMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    clickMe.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello World !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }
  }
```

I was wondering how I'm able to get reference to the Context object simply invoking

```
getApplicationContext()
```

inside `Toasts' makeText` method since I never instantiated Context (which I can't anyway since it's abstract) nor it's subclasses.

Can anyone please explain me when (or where) the reference was created and how come it's available in my class MainActivity?

A simple example with few classes to achieve the same will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Generally speaking, I'm not asking about "what is put at my disposal" because I know i've the reference to the `Context` object handy inside my class but "how it was put at my disposal"?

Answer (score 1):

`getApplicationContext()` Return the context of the **single, global Application object** of the current process.

This generally should only be used if you need a Context whose **lifecycle is separate from the current context**(i.e your Activity), that is tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component.

Consider for example how this interacts with registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter):

If used from an Activity context, the receiver is being registered within that activity. This means that you are expected to unregister before the activity is done being destroyed; in fact if you do not do so, the framework will clean up your leaked registration as it removes the activity and log an error. Thus, if you use the Activity context to register a receiver that is static (global to the process, not associated with an Activity instance) then that registration will be removed on you at whatever point the activity you used is destroyed.
If used from the Context returned here, the receiver is being registered with the global state associated with your application. Thus it will never be unregistered for you. This is necessary if the receiver is associated with static data, not a particular component. However using the ApplicationContext elsewhere can easily lead to serious leaks if you forget to unregister, unbind, etc.

**This piece of text is from the documentation of** `getApplicationContext()`;

Comment: Thanks, I've already read the documentation but it doesn't provide the answer to my question.

Comment: It answers your question "Can anyone please explain me when (or where) the reference was created and how come it's available in my class MainActivity?" When your app starts, then a global context is created

Answer (score 0):

Dont know what you are asking exactly, but your MainActivity extends Activity which extends some other classes which extend the Context class, which is where you get the getApplicationContext() method.

As per the [Context class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) docs: This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

Comment: Yes I know, as per android documentation, the implementation is provided by android system. I'm aware that the system created an instatnce of `Context` object (one of its subclasses) but I don't get "how" it's reference is available in my `MainActivìty class. Is the fact that `MainActivity `extends`Àctivity` suffice to get this reference? I don't think so

Comment: I'm not 100% sure without looking in some code, but I'd guess that when you create a Activity class (or any class that extends Context) the android system automatically initializes the reference to the application's context.